# SQLite file created by Core Data shows no schema

Tags: ios, sqlite, core-data

I've created a new iOS project using the master/detail template. The inserted list entries are stored between app restarts, so there must be a schema and data in the created SQLite database. But no matter how many items I insert something, that file (`~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.1/Applications/<GUID>/Documents/listtest.sqlite`) keeps the original size and has no schema (using `.schema` command of sqlite3).

So where's the actual database?

Comment: Can you specify why you need the database of core data as you won't be able to or at least should not access it directly?

Comment: Only for debugging purposes. I mean, the simulator data has to go somewhere.

Comment: Could it be, that you do not restart your app but resume it? I tried this scenario with an example project of Apple (Locations: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Locations/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008406) and found the sqlite file (with schema) at your given path. Check the project if this works for you, and if yes, compare the code.